# How can I solve "RhinoScriptEngineFactory cannot be cast to ScriptEngineFactory"?

Tags: jakarta-ee, groovy, jboss, migration, legacy

Recently I was asked to migrate a legacy web application from an old environment:

- JBoss EAP 4.0.2
- JDK 1.5 (Java SE Development Kit 5.0u22)

to a less old target environment:

- JBoss EAP 5.0.1
- JDK 1.6 (Java SE Development Kit 6u45)

but running a particular action on the new environment I got the error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngineFactory cannot be cast to javax.script.ScriptEngineFactory
    at javax.script.ScriptEngineManager.initEngines(ScriptEngineManager.java:109)
    at javax.script.ScriptEngineManager.access$0(ScriptEngineManager.java:86)
    at javax.script.ScriptEngineManager$1.run(ScriptEngineManager.java:80)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.script.ScriptEngineManager.init(ScriptEngineManager.java:78)
    at javax.script.ScriptEngineManager.<init>(ScriptEngineManager.java:51)
    ...
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    ...
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

How can I solve this exception?

## Update

The action which produce the exception above is related to Groovy Scripting Language provided by the `jsr223-1.0.jar` in the legacy web application.

Comment: I assume they know that Java 6 has been out of date for years and years? Like migrating from stone tablets to papyrus, whilst the rest of the world is off using computers?

Comment: Yes @tim_yates, they know. They have an environment migration plan and application are migrated accordingly with their own end of life and estimated migration costs. In this case the application will die before the target environment will be dismissed. The migration cost "from stone tablets to papyrus" was very low ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It's a JBoss class loader issue complicated by the JDK (1.5 to 1.6) migration.

[JDK 1.6 has included JSR 223 Scripting for the Java™ Platform API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/), so the `jsr223-1.0.jar` is no longer needed.

The solution which worked for me consisted in removing the `jsr223-1.0.jar` (credits to [Joseph Valerio and Santosh Singh](http://shibboleth.1660669.n2.nabble.com/IDP-2-2-0-Rhino-Exception-in-Jboss-td6049131.html)).

You might be interested in [reading the whole story](http://www.taringamberini.com/en/blog/java/javascript-dot-rhinoscriptenginefactory-cannot-be-cast-to-javax-dot-script-dot-scriptenginefactory-en/).